# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY:

Tags: android, json, jackson, ioexception

I am trying to save `SearchAvailableRidesRequestOffline` to android `Shared Preferences`. I need to `deserialise` the object to use it later on. While I try to `deserialise` it from `json`, I am getting this exception.

**IOException**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class com.mnox.webservices.core.ARequest
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "request" : {
     .....
        "filterType"[truncated 882 chars]; line: 2, column: 15] (through reference chain: com.mnox.paymentgateway.commons.support.offline.SearchAvailableRidesRequestOffline["request"])
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "request" : {
    //
    // SearchAvailableRidesRequest
    // Parameters
  },
  "concreateRequestClass" : "com.mnox.webservices.requests.v2.SearchAvailableRidesRequest",
  "currentActivity" : null,
  "maxLimitAllowed" : 1000,
  "priority" : 0,
  "requestType" : "mNoxSearch"
}
```

**Java**

```
public class SearchAvailableRidesRequestOffline extends AOfflineRequest implements IModelRequestedController {

    public SearchAvailableRidesRequestOffline() {
    }

    public SearchAvailableRidesRequestOffline(SearchAvailableRidesRequest searchRequest) {
        super(searchRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public int getMaxLimitAllowed() {
        return 1000;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPriority() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onModelRequestCompleted(IModelRequestedController context, int modelIdentifier,
                                        Object modelData) {

    }

    @Override
    public RequestType getRequestType() {
        return RequestType.mNoxSearch;
    }


    @Override
    public Activity getCurrentActivity() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class getConcreateRequestClass() { return SearchAvailableRidesRequest.class;} ;

}
public abstract class AOfflineRequest {

    public static enum RequestType { mNoxSearch, mNoxDriverCurrentLocation} ;

    private ARequest request;
    public AOfflineRequest(ARequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
    public void updatePreExecuteProgressBar() {

    }

    public void updatePostExecuteProgressBar() {

    }

    public abstract RequestType getRequestType() ;
    public abstract Class getConcreateRequestClass() ;
    public abstract int getMaxLimitAllowed();
    public abstract int getPriority();

    //
    // For gson
    //
    public AOfflineRequest() {
    }
    public ARequest getRequest() {
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just code and no time to write any words? what you are doing and when do you get this exception?

Comment: Sorry, making corrections now.. Seems crazy :)

Comment: Try adding a `private setRequest(ARequest)` method as well and see if that helps

Comment: Nope does not work, tried that.

Comment: What is the source object that you try to serialize?

Comment: SearchAvailableRidesRequestOffline I am trying to serialize

Comment: I'm 99% sure that "request" field in response should be an json array instead of json object. To clarify this you can check the structure of class which object you want to obtain.

Comment: ok let mecheck that out..

Comment: @Siddharth please read my answer, do you have a class that to mapping the response, please add this class?

Comment: @Siddharth your JSON example is incompleted.  Can you provide a fuller version.  It should includes the parts relevant to the error message you are getting: `"filterType"[truncated 882 chars]; line: 2, column: 15]`)

Answer (score 2):

Remember:

> - if the .json content starts with **{** is considered as a **Json Object**.
> - if the .json content starts with **[** is considered as a **Json Array**.

You have this error

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException:
>   Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY:

because you are expecting an Json Array but your response is a Json Object:

```
"{
  "request" : {
   ...
   ...
```

Check your response.